# set height and width of jwplayer in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, jwplayer

I am trying to set the height and width of the `jwplayer` using jquery. Its working fine in all the desktop systems. but in `Ipad`, its not working properly. It showing the vertical scroll bar. I using the following calculation.

```
jwpwt = ((document.documentElement.clientWidth/100)*70);
jwpht = ((document.documentElement.clientHeight/100)*65);

jwplayer('container_video').setup({
    flashplayer: '/media/js/player.swf',
    file:$("#"+temp).val(),
    height: jwpht,
    width: popwt,
    stretching :'exactfit',
    skin:'/media/images/modieus/modieus/modieus.xml',
    autostart: true
});
```

I dont know, which percentage have to give for `ipad` window. Anyone can help? Please!

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer is loading different elements on mobile device and desktop (you can inspect element on your ipad version using safari develop mode). 
I was trying to resize the player dynamically using width:100% height:100% and stretch:uniform. It worked on desktop but not iPad either.
I guess for your case, you can try to put jwplayer inside a container. You set width and height of container. and for jwplayer, using my method, set width:100%, height:100%

Not sure if it helps.. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jwplayer("myElement").setup({
         ......
         width: '100%',
         .....
   });
</script>
```